# simple Java problem

Tags: java, android

Example 1 - works

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button touchedButton = (Button) v;

        Test (MainScreen.this, touchedButton.getId());
         }

    public  void Test (MainScreen mainscreen, int touchedButton) {

    if (touchedButton == R.id.serviceButton )
    startService(new Intent(mainscreen, SimpleService.class));

    if (touchedButton == R.id.cancelButton)
    stopService(new Intent(mainscreen, SimpleService.class));
}
}
```

Example 2 – does not work

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button touchedButton = (Button) v;

        Secondary.Test (MainScreen.this, touchedButton.getId());
          }
}


public class Secondary  extends Activity {


public  void Test (MainScreen mainscreen, int touchedButton) {

    if (touchedButton == R.id.serviceButton )
    startService(new Intent(mainscreen,SimpleService.class));

    if (touchedButton == R.id.cancelButton)
    stopService(new Intent(mainscreen,SimpleService.class));
         }
}
```

Why does Example 2 not work?

Comment: Do you mean that it does not compile, or that it does the wrong thing when it runs?

Comment: How does it "not work".  What did you expect to happen and what is actually happening?  Does the error occur when you compile or when you run?

Comment: You should include information about you error. By example: "it doesn't compile and the compiler says I cannot invoke a non-static method from a static context" or something like that.

Comment: Think about an appropriate title. 90% of the questions here are problems, and if you think it is easy, solve it yourself. Don't read this as an insult.

Comment: Why does this question have upvotes :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to call a non-static method statically on this line:

```
Secondary.Test (MainScreen.this, touchedButton.getId());
```

You need to create an instance of `Secondary` and call `Test()` on the instance or change `Secondary.Test()` to be a static method like this:

```
public static void Test (MainScreen mainscreen, int touchedButton) {
```

Comment: I actually did create an instance and it does not work. I in writing the question I goofed.

Comment: @EliFromToronto you can't create an instance of a class that extends `Activity`.  You have still not said in what way it "does not work" though.

Comment: I think the problem is in "mainscreen" but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @EliFromToronto that's nice, but you haven't actually stated *what the problem is* yet, just a vague: "it doesn't work".